# Dapper passing dynamic param

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I am currently in the process of writing a wrapper for Dapper.  This wrapper forces every query to be a stored procedure.

In my wrapper, I am calling Dapper like so (with the problem):

```
public IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(string storedProcName, dynamic param) {
    IEnumerable<T> results;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString) {
        results = connection.Query<T>(storedProcName, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    return results;
}
```

When I try to pass "param" to the Query, it tells me "Cannot resolve symbol Query."  When I remove the param pass, it works fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction so that I can pass dynamic params (or something like it) on to Dapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change param to type object and when you call it you can use an anonymous type to pass in your params.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(string storedProcName, object param) {
    IEnumerable<T> results;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString) {
        results = connection.Query<T>(storedProcName, param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
var results = query.Select<Entity>("spname", new { Id = 2, Something = "test" });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just cast it away:

```
results = connection.Query<T>(storedProcName,
    (object)param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I'm re-doubting the wisdom of that `dynamic`; I know there was a reason, but I suspect it causes more harm than good. Frankly, dapper would work fine with `object` (the "reason" was an IDE issue, not a language issue).